# Python: How to create unique list-type object on initialization of default function argument?

Tags: python

There is a class, which constructor takes an argument of "list type". Default value of this argument is empty list. Constructor uses this argument to initialize one of class data members.
Then, when I create two different instance objects of this class, both of them points to te same list. Why is that?

I've tried to set default value to None, and then conditionally create new empty list in the class constructor body. And this works. Different object instances have different list in their class data members.
But I would like to know why it doesn't work as I would expect, when I create a list in function argument default value init, like in the code below:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, user_list=list()):
        self.__class_list = user_list

    def addSomethingToList(self, a, b):
        self.__class_list.append([a,b])

    def whoAmI(self):
        return hex(id(self.__class_list))

    def getList(self):
        return self.__class_list

A = myClass()
B = myClass()

A.addSomethingToList(1,2)
B.addSomethingToList(33,44)

print("A",A.whoAmI(), A.getList())
print("B",B.whoAmI(), B.getList())

##################
#Expected results:
A 0x7f6dd49a6108 [[1, 2]]
B 0x7f6dd49a6148 [[33, 44]]

#Actual results:
A 0x7f736f1f40c8 [[1, 2], [33, 44]]
B 0x7f736f1f40c8 [[1, 2], [33, 44]]
```

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Hitch Hicker's python guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas)

Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called (like it is in say, Ruby). This means that if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well.